# Where is the list of closed beta sites?

Tags: support, beta-sites, closed-sites

When I know the name of the site that was closed during public beta, I can search for that site in Area51 search.

However, is there any place where I can find the list of all closed public betas? I'm just curious to find out, what were the reasons for particular sites to fail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find at least some of them by [searching for the close message](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aarea51.stackexchange.com+%22didn%27t+have+enough+activity+during+the+beta%22).

Comment: Thanks for tip. I haven't thought there are so many of them.

Comment: Is there an official list anywhere?